# How to get next available year from DD-MON date format and have it in DD-MM-YYYY format?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How do I add the next available year to the following date format first. So for example if the date is July and today it is June it will be 2023. But if the date is January and today is June then it will be 2024 because January has already passed. The dates are in a very strange format of `DD-MON` and the system I need to upload to won't take this format and required the correct year depending on the date.

```
Select '07-Jul'
From sys.dual

Select '08-Oct'
From sys.dual
```

The desired result will be 07-07-2023 and 08-10-2024.

I am using Oracle SQL

Comment: Is it a column in a table? Does the value have a Varchar2 datatype? Are the values in columns like '07-Jul' or did you trim it?

Comment: "today is June then it will be 2024 because October has already passed" But if today is June then October will not have already passed.

Comment: Yes they are varchar2 and they are in the format '07-Jul'. I have not trimmed it

Comment: Apologies I have fixed the October line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `TO_DATE`, a `CASE` expression and `ADD_MONTHS`:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN TO_DATE('07-Jul', 'DD-Mon', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') >= SYSDATE
       THEN TO_DATE('07-Jul', 'DD-Mon', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
       ELSE ADD_MONTHS(
              TO_DATE('07-Jul', 'DD-Mon', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'),
              12
            )
       END
FROM   dual
```

If you want the output as a formatted string (rather than as a `DATE`, which is a binary data-type and has no format) then you can wrap it in `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         CASE
         WHEN TO_DATE('07-Jul', 'DD-Mon', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') >= SYSDATE
         THEN TO_DATE('07-Jul', 'DD-Mon', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
         ELSE ADD_MONTHS(
                TO_DATE('07-Jul', 'DD-Mon', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'),
                12
              )
         END,
         'DD-MM-YYYY'
       )
FROM   dual
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that isnt working. It is returning values for October as 2023 when they should be 2024 and returning values for May as 2024 when they should be 2023 as May has already passed this year.

Comment: @jamster126 December has not passed so it should be 2023. May has passed so it should be 2024. That is exactly the logic that you asked for. If you want it to be the other way round then change `>=` to `<` (but that is not the logic requested in the question).

Comment: Thank you apologies again for mix up. That worked :)